# How to properly mount the extra hard disk space?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems

I am asking for help on how to properly mount the extra hard disk space.
Here is my situation.

Running fdisk -l, give this result

```
root@ ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14        1058     8393962+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            1059        7457    51399967+  83  Linux
```

But on checking on the directadmin and `mount` command, i see this result.

```
/dev/sda1   99M 12M 82M 13% /boot
/dev/sda3   48G 9.4G    36G 21% /
```

From what I can see, the /dev/sda2 is not mounted. Or in my understanding, I have over 1500GB of space that I cannot used? Am I right with this assumption?

What am i going to do so that the remaining disk space will be seen on directadmin and it can be used for my mysql and domain files? As I have over 1TB of xml files that will be parsed and transfered to mysql database.

Please help me. I am new to this thing.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

That's your swap partition; it shouldn't be mounted.

Your missing space is due to the fact that a lot of space on the disk is simply not used by any of the partitions; you'll want to extend your root partition or create a new partition to utilize the space.

Comment: Thanks Shane. So my option eiter to extend the root(sda1) or create a new partition. Which of the two would you recommend(the easiest and secured)? Considering that space should be used for mysql and my php/web files? thanks. (My question maybe dumb. I'm new to this. Please be.)

Comment: @JanMark Your root partition is `/dev/sda3`, not `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: @JanMark My recommendation during the OS install would have been to mount the extra partition on `/var`. If you do that now, you're looking at needing to migrate data from the root volume's `/var` over to the new parition. So, the simplest solution is probably to simply extend `sda3` - grab a [gparted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), boot to it, and expand that partition and filesystem to use the free space.